# OmniFaces throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource handler class org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler is duplicated

Tags: jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

I've updated to Omnifaces 3.3 using build.gradle:

```
compile group: 'org.omnifaces', name: 'omnifaces', version: '3.3'
```

My EAR can run with 3.2, but I get the following errors when deploy 3.3:

```
21:07:07,856 INFO  [org.omnifaces.ApplicationInitializer] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) Using OmniFaces version 3.3
21:07:07,876 INFO  [io.undertow.websockets.jsr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) UT026005: Adding programmatic server endpoint class org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketEndpoint for path /omnifaces.push/{channel}
21:07:07,878 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) Initializing Mojarra 2.3.9.SP01 for context '/GoStopHandle'
21:07:08,523 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) Monitoring file:/usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/16.0.0.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/deployment/deploymentbed7dce99d600c8e/GoStopHandleWAR.war-4113c165328ad65/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
21:07:08,527 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) Running on PrimeFaces 7.0.5
21:07:08,527 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) Running on PrimeFaces 7.0.5
21:07:08,527 SEVERE [org.omnifaces.ApplicationProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) OmniFaces failed to initialize! Report an issue to OmniFaces.: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource handler class org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler is duplicated. This will result in erratic resource handling behavior. Please check your faces-config.xml files, also in web fragment JAR files.
    at deployment.GoStopHandle.ear.GoStopHandleWAR.war//org.omnifaces.ApplicationProcessor.checkDuplicateResourceHandler(ApplicationProcessor.java:88)
    at deployment.GoStopHandle.ear.GoStopHandleWAR.war//org.omnifaces.ApplicationProcessor.processEvent(ApplicationProcessor.java:72)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:123)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.Events.processListeners(Events.java:253)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.Events.invokeListenersFor(Events.java:231)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.Events.publishEvent(Events.java:115)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:127)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:788)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:788)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.publishPostConfigEvent(ConfigManager.java:553)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:264)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:216)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:250)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)

21:07:08,528 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) Critical error during deployment: : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource handler class org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler is duplicated. This will result in erratic resource handling behavior. Please check your faces-config.xml files, also in web fragment JAR files.
    at deployment.GoStopHandle.ear.GoStopHandleWAR.war//org.omnifaces.ApplicationProcessor.checkDuplicateResourceHandler(ApplicationProcessor.java:88)
    at deployment.GoStopHandle.ear.GoStopHandleWAR.war//org.omnifaces.ApplicationProcessor.processEvent(ApplicationProcessor.java:72)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:123)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.Events.processListeners(Events.java:253)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.Events.invokeListenersFor(Events.java:231)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.Events.publishEvent(Events.java:115)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:127)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:788)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:788)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.publishPostConfigEvent(ConfigManager.java:553)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:264)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:216)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:250)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)

21:07:08,529 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."GoStopHandle.ear"."GoStopHandleWAR.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."GoStopHandle.ear"."GoStopHandleWAR.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource handler class org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler is duplicated. This will result in erratic resource handling behavior. Please check your faces-config.xml files, also in web fragment JAR files.
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource handler class org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler is duplicated. This will result in erratic resource handling behavior. Please check your faces-config.xml files, also in web fragment JAR files.
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:252)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource handler class org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler is duplicated. This will result in erratic resource handling behavior. Please check your faces-config.xml files, also in web fragment JAR files.
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:283)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:216)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:250)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource handler class org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler is duplicated. This will result in erratic resource handling behavior. Please check your faces-config.xml files, also in web fragment JAR files.
    at deployment.GoStopHandle.ear.GoStopHandleWAR.war//org.omnifaces.ApplicationProcessor.checkDuplicateResourceHandler(ApplicationProcessor.java:88)
    at deployment.GoStopHandle.ear.GoStopHandleWAR.war//org.omnifaces.ApplicationProcessor.processEvent(ApplicationProcessor.java:72)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:123)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.Events.processListeners(Events.java:253)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.Events.invokeListenersFor(Events.java:231)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.Events.publishEvent(Events.java:115)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:127)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:788)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:788)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.publishPostConfigEvent(ConfigManager.java:553)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:264)
    ... 22 more

21:07:08,533 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "GoStopHandle.ear")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"GoStopHandle.ear\".\"GoStopHandleWAR.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource handler class org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler is duplicated. This will result in erratic resource handling behavior. Please check your faces-config.xml files, also in web fragment JAR files.
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource handler class org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler is duplicated. This will result in erratic resource handling behavior. Please check your faces-config.xml files, also in web fragment JAR files.
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource handler class org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler is duplicated. This will result in erratic resource handling behavior. Please check your faces-config.xml files, also in web fragment JAR files.
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource handler class org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler is duplicated. This will result in erratic resource handling behavior. Please check your faces-config.xml files, also in web fragment JAR files."}}
21:07:08,533 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "GoStopHandle.ear" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"GoStopHandle.ear\".\"GoStopHandleWAR.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource handler class org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler is duplicated. This will result in erratic resource handling behavior. Please check your faces-config.xml files, also in web fragment JAR files.
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource handler class org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler is duplicated. This will result in erratic resource handling behavior. Please check your faces-config.xml files, also in web fragment JAR files.
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource handler class org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler is duplicated. This will result in erratic resource handling behavior. Please check your faces-config.xml files, also in web fragment JAR files.
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource handler class org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler is duplicated. This will result in erratic resource handling behavior. Please check your faces-config.xml files, also in web fragment JAR files."}}
21:07:08,545 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'GoStopHandle.ear/GoStopHandleJAR.jar#goStopHandleMongoDBPersistenceUnit'
21:07:08,551 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.beans] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) HHH10005004: Stopping BeanContainer : org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.internal.CdiBeanContainerExtendedAccessImpl@6f289f7f
21:07:08,551 INFO  [org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) OGM001202: Closing connection to MongoDB
21:07:08,551 INFO  [org.mongodb.driver.connection] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:43}] to 127.0.0.1:27017 because the pool has been closed.
21:07:08,552 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'GoStopHandle.ear/GoStopHandleJAR.jar#goStopHandleMongoDBPersistenceUnit'
21:07:08,563 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0208: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: GoStopHandleJAR.jar) in 29ms
21:07:08,591 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0208: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: GoStopHandleWAR.war) in 57ms
21:07:08,594 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment GoStopHandle.ear (runtime-name: GoStopHandle.ear) in 60ms
21:07:10,525 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (Mojarra-WebResourceMonitor-2-thread-1) Unable to access url file:/usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/16.0.0.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/deployment/deploymentbed7dce99d600c8e/GoStopHandleWAR.war-4113c165328ad65/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml.  Monitoring for this resource will no longer occur.
21:15:46,752 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) WFLYDR0009: Content /usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/16.0.0.Final/standalone/data/content/71/89ba9c42dac295cdb4b7e9ccf47471afd95a22 is obsolete and will be removed
21:15:46,756 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) WFLYDR0002: Content removed from location /usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/16.0.0.Final/standalone/data/content/71/89ba9c42dac295cdb4b7e9ccf47471afd95a22/content
```

I run with:

> PrimeFace (Elite) 7.0.5 OmniFaces 3.2
>
> Java openjdk 11.0.2 Kotlin 1.3.41
>
> JBoss WildFly 16.0.0.FINAL Undertow 2.0.19.Final Mojarra 2.3.9.SP01
>
> Google Chrome Version 75.0.3770.100 (64-bit) Safari 12.1
>   (14607.1.40.1.4) macOS Mojave 10.14.5

Comment: Did you check your faces-config.xml files, also in web fragment JAR files?

Comment: Looks to me like some configuration error causing PrimeFaces to start up twice.

Comment: It always worked for many years as Omnifaces 3.2. The errors have occurred since 3.3. So the only change I was: compile group: 'org.omnifaces', name: 'omnifaces', version: '3.3'

Comment: You need to remove the duplicate PrimeFaces library.

Comment: Agreed it looks like you have 2 different PrimeFaces Jars in your class path.

Answer (score 2):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource handler class org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler is duplicated. This will result in erratic resource handling behavior. Please check your faces-config.xml files, also in web fragment JAR files.

OmniFaces 3.3 has indeed [introduced](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/whatsnew) a preventive check for duplicate resource handlers in JSF configuration. See [issue 504](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/504).

In your specific case, however, this literal error message is a bit unhelpful because in this specific case it's not necessarily caused by a developer mistake in `faces-config.xml` file in your WAR or web fragment JAR files.

It's actually caused by a developer mistake in build or runtime configuration. Your build and/or runtime classpath ended up getting duplicate PrimeFaces JAR files which each registered their own `PrimeResourceHandler` via their own `faces-config.xml` file. The PrimeFaces JAR file is essentially also a "web fragment JAR file", but actually not a custom one (hence the error message being slightly unhelpful for starters, I'll improve that for the next OmniFaces version).

In order to solve your problem you need to make sure that there's **only one** PrimeFaces JAR file in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the produced WAR file, and that there are no duplicates throughout the runtime classpath. In case your application is in EAR format, you also need to make sure that *no one* web fragment JAR file ends up in `/lib` folder of the produced EAR file. In case you deploy to a custom built server stack, you also need to make sure that *no one* web fragment JAR file is manually placed in default classpath of the server (e.g. `/lib` folder of Tomcat). In case you deploy to a custom built Java environment, you also need to make sure that *no one* web fragment JAR file is manually placed in default classpath of the JRE (e.g. `/lib` folder of JRE installation).

Comment: I only have one version of PrimeFaces JAR (compile group: 'org.primefaces', name: 'primefaces', version: '7.0.5') which is in file '\lib'. I have '  compile group: 'org.omnifaces', name: 'omnifaces', version: '3.3'. If use 'omnifaces', version: '3.2' it works fine. An older versio of 'primefaces-6.2.10.jar' works wih '3,2' as well. If I create my Primefaces with '7.0.5' and '3,2'. It creates the WAR,  JAR & the EAR is disployed in './standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 --server-config=standalone-full.xml' and it runs. My the way I use 'build.gradle'.

Comment: *"... which is in file '\lib' ..."* this is thus wrong. Web fragment JARs do absolutely not belong there. Make sure it ends up in /WEB-INF/lib of the WAR, as instructed.

Comment: I noticed you unaccepted the answer without leaving an explanation. What problem exactly are you facing now? You posted two comments in other related questions that everything is now working fine for you.